# Is it possible to disable loaded fonts for a website directly from the browser?

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, fonts

I want to quickly see how the fallback-fonts is working for a website by excluding one or more specific fonts. Is this possible in Chrome? How?

Have searched for it with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy with the Chrome Inspector. You just have to find the HTML lines which include your custom font (Or in your CSS) and delete it.

Of course you can just modifiy your css directly in Chrome to see what happens.

UPDATE: Delete directly the font in the sources tab in you Chrome Inspector.

Comment: I know you can do that. But the font is used in many places in the css file. I had hoped for a quicker solution.

Comment: Ok ! Is it a custo font which is loaded externaly (like Google fonts ?)

Comment: These are from Fonts.com. But it would be great to just choose any font.